# Using ASP.NET Web API to call Java Web Service

Tags: java, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Web API which is supposed to call a java addition web service. When i run the java web service and type url `http://localhost:8080/addition/9/6` i get `{"firstNumber":9,"secondNumber":6,"sum":15}`as the output data. Right now, i want to use the ASP.NET Web API to call and display that data when i run the ASP.NET Web API application. How do i go about doing that?

Here are my codes:

**ASP.NET Web API Codes**

RestfulClient.cs

```
public class RestfulClient     
{
    private string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/addition/";
    public Task<string> addition()
    {
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("addition").Result;
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.html");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

ApiController.cs

```
private RestfulClient restfulClient = new RestfulClient();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var Result1 = restfulClient.addition().Result;
        return Content(Result1);
    }
```

**Java Web Service Codes**

AdditionController.java

```
@RestController
public class AdditionController {

private static final String template = " %s";
private static int getSum;

@RequestMapping("/addition/{param1}/{param2}")
@ResponseBody 

public Addition getSum 
            (@PathVariable("param1") int firstNumber,@PathVariable("param2") int secondNumber) {
return new Addition(
        (String.format(template, firstNumber)), String.format(template, secondNumber));
  }
}
```

Someone please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but please make your HttpClient a static instance through your application (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) and this [blog post](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)).

Comment: By the way, you have to `await` async methods, otherwise you don't get their results. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Ok noted thank you so much

Comment: @SusmithaNaidu What is the current problem?

Comment: @Nkosi Currently, when i run the ASP.NET application, i get: `{"timestamp":1509075938753,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException","message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"{9}\"","path":"/addition/%7B9%7D/addition"}` instead of **{"firstNumber":9,"secondNumber":6,"sum":15}**

Comment: I would like to know, how should i change my restfulClient.cs class so that i get the output that i want.

Comment: At first, when my java web service did not take in any parameters, this restfulClient.cs class worked. However when i added parameters to my java web service, this class does not work. I am not sure on how i should edit it. Could you please guide me through?

Comment: The URL you are calling from the client is not formatted correctly according to your base URL and the one used in the GetAsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Java service, the URL you are calling from the client is not formatted correctly based on your base URL and the one used in the `GetAsync`.

```
public class RestfulClient {
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static RestfulClient() {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> addition(int a, int b) {
        try {
            var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", a, b);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.html");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The controller would also need to be updated.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
    int a = 9;
    int b = 6;
    var result = await restfulClient.addition(a, b);
    return Content(result);
}
```

Note the proper use of the `HttpClient` as suggested in the comments and as well as the use of async/await.

Comment: I get the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'RestfulClient.BASE_URL'`

Comment: Ok i solved it. Added `private static string BASE_URL`

Comment: This was what i was looking for. Thank you so much!